# Java Compare and update large files

Tags: java, performance, file, file-io

Here's my problem statement. I have 3 large text files (each <5GB) each with 100 million lines (records). I want to compare files 1 and 2 and update the value in file 3. A single record in each file would look like this:

### File 1

PrimaryValue1|OldValue1

### File 2

PrimaryValue1|NewValue1

### File 3

Field1Value|Field2Value|Field3Value|OldValue1|Field5Value....|Field100Value

All I have for every record is the **OldValue1**, which is unique for every record. Now, Using the '**PrimaryValue1**', I need to get the **NewValue1** corresponding to the **OldValue1** using files 1&2, and then update this **NewValue1** in file3 in place of **OldValue1**. Both OldValue and NewValue are unique for every record.

I understand that if I read all the files into memory, then I will be able to compare and replace the values. Since this could be memory-intensive, I would like to know if there are better approaches to handle this scenario.

Comment: *Since this could be memory-intensive* There is little worse than premature optimisation.  Try your approach, and only think about optimisation if it's proven to be memory-intensive.

Comment: @JBNizet My files are sitting in S3, thats why I have to read the whole file at once.

Comment: @JBNizet So then wouldn't I have to maintain/re-establish S3 connections throughout the process? There are 100 millions records in each file.

Comment: All my previous comments assumes you wanted to find and replace *one* OldValue. Not all.You can disregard them now.

Comment: Ok, cool. I've updated the problem statement like you suggested, so that its more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

File1 and File2 define the replacements that you have to apply to File3.

I'd do the following steps:

- Read File2 into a HashMap `newValues`.
- Read File1, and for every entry:

  - Look up the primary value in `newValues`.
  - If found, put the old value / new value pair into a HashMap `replacement`.
  - Delete the entry from `newValues` (I guess, there are no duplicates).
- Read File3, and for every entry :

  - Do the replacements from the `replacement` Map.
  - Write the resulting line to the output.

You need memory for the replacements, but the main file can be processed sequentially, needing just one record buffer.

If you get an OutOfMemoryError, this will probably happen while building the replacement Map, before you start working on the main File3. You can then modify the program to work on managable chunks of File2. The rest of the algorithm need not change.

Comment: After writing my answer: you want to do all replacements OldValue -> NewValue? Or do you have a single OldValue and only want that single one replaced? In that case, my answer wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: No, you were right, its about replacing all old values with new values.

Comment: @Amith Ah, you should really clarify your question then, because it says otherwise: *All I have is the OldValue. Now, Using the 'PrimaryValue1', I need to get the NewValue*.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, so I just mentioned OldValue since I was just talking about a single record in the example. Let me edit it so that it'll be more clear.